# What does class*="class_name-" mean?

Tags: css

What is the * after class for and why is it between brackets? I found this code in a codepen and was wondering what was it for?

```css
[class*="funLine-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left:1vw; 
    padding-right:1vw; 
}
```

Comment: [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp